# Accepted answers for questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Too often there are questions with one (or several) good answers, that have even been upvoted substantially, yet the OP hasn't deigned (for whatever reason) to accept any of them.

That little green tick really helps the audience weigh the value of the respective answer, and highlights whether the community is in obviously full agreement or if it's not a simple answer, regardless of votes.

How much against SE's guidance (and software capabilities) is the concept of a moderated and/or community-driven "answer acceptance" process?

i.e. answers with X amount of unaccepted answers, with a minimum of Y votes or whatever the algorithm, are punted into a Review queue to be "forcibly" accepted.

(yes, I realize this can apply to most if not all SE communities, but Writers is rather susceptible to subjective complexity which lends the green tick greater weight)

Answer (score 1):

This has been requested many times across the network, and the response from SE has been "no". (When I'm not on mobile I'll try to provide links.) The acceptance mark is the OP's to give, withhold, or neglect entirely.

However, don't ascribe too much value to that mark. All it means is "the OP liked this best". Sometimes it's not the best answer; sometimes it's even downvoted! Read the answers, look at the votes, and decide which answer(s) *you* trust most.

Comment: In point of fact, there is a gold badge awarded if your answer outscores the accepted answer by more than 2X, so just because the OP prefers an answer doesn't mean the community does.

Comment: [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users) is the most obvious, but there are a few others that are similar.